# Creating specific value sequence in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, sequence

I need to create an oracle sequence with specific values

> FOUR0001, FOUR0002, FOUR0003.....

the increment must be in order.

Comment: Create a normal sequence and append the 'FOUR'  with padded zeros in your application code

Comment: how do you exactly append it?

Comment: create sequence "FOUR_SEQ"
start with 'FOUR' += 0209
increment by 1
nocache
nocycle
noorder
/

Comment: See also this answer to a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14561364/3061852

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a simple sequence

```
create sequence my_seq ; --start with 1 increment by 1
```

In your application code / table where you use the sequence to store the data, use something like this

```
INSERT INTO yourtab (col1) VALUES( 'FOUR'||lpad(my_seq.nextval,4,'0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sequence:

```
create sequence SEQ_NAME ...;
```

and then to create a trigger to feed the field automatically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INS_TABLENAME
  before insert on TABLENAME
  for each row

BEGIN

  if :new.FIELD_NAME is null then
    :new.FIELD_NAME := 'FOUR'||lpad(SEQ_NAME.nextval,4,'0');
  end if;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sequence starting with 210 ( because i already ahve 209 records) then created the trigger bellow

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger BIU_FRS  
  before insert or update on FOURNISSEUR             
  for each row 
begin  
  if :NEW.FRS_NUM is null then
    select ('FOUR'||lpad(four_seq.nextval,4,'0')) into :NEW.FRS_NUM from dual;
  end if;
  if inserting then
        :new.created    := localtimestamp;
        :new.created_by := nvl(wwv_flow.g_user,user);
    end if;
    :new.updated    := localtimestamp;
    :new.updated_by := nvl(wwv_flow.g_user,user);
end;
```

thank you @Kaushik Nayak and @Diego Souza